# IntelliJ does not compile my project when I update jar in my local maven repository

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I created a ***maven*** project with lots of external dependencies. I was able to build it fine. Then I installed new **SNAPSHOT** of dependency into my local maven repository.

First maven itself was not picking up latest SNAPSHOT. I deleted the old SNAPSHOT. This caused maven to pick up the new SNAPSHOT and I was able to compile against new jar from `mvn` command line but now `IntelliJ` is not recognizing any of my imports and I cannot build from `IntelliJ` (*although mvn package works*).

How to fix this? If I create a brand new project from same sources in a new folder then `IntelliJ` works.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144540/intellij-with-maven-compilation

Answer (score 1):

In the upper left corner, right-click on your project and re-import Maven. That sometimes works for me. In some cases even that fails, and honestly I've just gone into the M2 repository (~/.m2), and deleted all copies of that particular library. That forces a rebuild as well and seems to work.

I'll be curious to see if someone has a better answer ...